# Set string value from clipboard contents C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clipboard

I'm writing a small app that should display the number of characters in the current string from the clipboard. So for example, someone highlights a line of text and hits copy, then runs my app. I want it to display the number of characters in the string. Should be simple, but I keep getting Zero returned. There are related threads but none answer my question. Here is what I have so far (Its a console app btw.):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BuildandRun
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = Clipboard.GetText();
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            int dataLength = data.Length;
            Console.WriteLine(dataLength + " Characters.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e.aspx):

> The Clipboard class can only be used in threads set to single thread
>   apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method
>   is marked with the STAThreadAttribute attribute.

Just change your code to:

```
[STAThreadAttribute]
static void Main( string[] args )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Clipboard` only works for Single Threaded Apartment threads.

Therefore the answer is to add the following to Main():

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
```

Or workaround like this:

```
public string GetClipboardText()
{
    string result = "";

    Thread thread = new Thread(() => result = Clipboard.GetText());
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

    return result;
}
```